# I want to autoplay Clip path revealing slider by given span of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I want to autoplay the clip path revealing slider. here is my pen: 
`<https://codepen.io/uibeast/pen/xdNBVJ>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying you want to implement an Autoplay feature? 
In that case, add the following lines after line 6 in your code:

```
var nextSlide = document.querySelector('.slider__control--right');
setInterval(()=>{ nextSlide.click() }, 3000);
```

Bear in-mind, this is a very basic example. The 3000 number means the the slider will automatically rotate every 3sec.